# How to stop <mat-expansion-panel> from triggering with outside button clicks

Tags: angular, events, toggle, panel

Mat expansion keeps toggling by clicking of outside buttons on the page.It should toggle only by clicking the trigger icon (downward/upward arrow)on its panel.

---

```
 mat-expansion-panel [expanded]=expandBox *ngIf="BoxEnable">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
                    <span class="title_text"><b>{{Box_title}}</b></span>
                    <span (click)="addNote($event)" matTooltip="Add Text" class="notes-add-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(click)="event.stopPropagation()"` to stop event bubbling

Comment: it is not recommended to do that, you don't know what you break with that. https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/